# win32 List View Abbreviating Text

Tags: c++, winapi, listview, user-interface, text

I'm using win32 to create a list view with downloaded icons, however, the text is abbreviated at approximately 19 characters (as about size 12 font, Segoe UI). I have included the CreateWindow and item creation code I'm using for it.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
HWND airlinelist = CreateWindow(WC_LISTVIEW,L"",WS_CHILD | LVS_LIST | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER,18,104,323,74,hwnd,(HMENU)3,hinst,NULL);

                    LVITEM newi;
                    ZeroMemory(&newi,sizeof(LVITEM));                       
                    const wchar_t* n = L"Client Website Name, website.com"  
                    newi.pszText = newc;                            
                    newi.mask = LVIF_TEXT | LVIF_IMAGE;
                    newi.iImage = 0;                            
                    ListView_InsertItem(airlinelist,&newi);
```

The above would create a list view with the icon and something to the effect of "Client Website Nam..." despite it only taking up half of the list view's width.

Comment: What mode is the ListView in (icon, list, report, etc)? If report, is there a column defined that is only wide enough to accomodate 19 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you're using `LVS_LIST` mode because the style is shown in your code sample. You can use the [`LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761163%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message to adjust the column size once you've added items to the list control. You can also use the [`ListView_SetColumnWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro. E.g.:

```
SendMessage(airlinelist, LVM_SETCOLUMNWIDTH, 0, 300);
```

This would set the columns to 300 pixels wide. If you're actually using `LVS_REPORT` mode you would need to set the width for each column individually.